# AWS Lambda postgres connection timing out, but only on first attempt

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am using Lambda to connect to a Postgres RDS instance that is a part of a VPC. If the Lambda function has not been invoked in a while, it will get the following error after about 2 minutes of execution:

```
could not connect to postgres { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
```

**When the lambda function retries, it successfully connects to the database and executes as it should.**

The Lambda function is written for node.js using the node-postgres package. The program to connect looks something like this:

```
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect(function(err) {
    console.log("client connected");
    if(err) {
         context.fail('Connection failed');  
    }
    else { //do stuff }
}
```

The log shows that it is never reaching the "client connected" before timing out. What is going wrong during these first attempts?

Note: If the lambda function is invoked again within 20-30 minutes then this timeout does not occur and the function executes successfully.

Comment: I'm guessing it's trying to reuse an old connection to the database, but the connection has timed out. Are you calling `client.end()` before exiting your Lambda function?

Comment: Also I've been reading about some issues with ENI creation time when using Lambda functions with VPC access that aren't called extremely often. You might have to increase your database connection timeout if you can, to account for the extra time it will take to get a network connection whenever Amazon spins up a new instance of your Lambda function.

Comment: client.end() is being called so there are no connections being left open. The ENI creation time sounds like a good theory because subsequent invocations or retries don't have the same issue. I'll look into increasing the database timeout and put the lambda function to its maximum timeout as well.

Comment: I am having the same problem as Toast, I tried your suggestion @MarkB with increasing the timeout to the DB but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Answer (score -4):

this issue happend with me too, after some minutes without use lambda when i try to invoke lambda function in first attempt i get

> {"errorMessage":"connect
>   ETIMEDOUT","errorType":"SequelizeConnectionError","stackTrace":["Handshake._callback
>   (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:94:20)","Handshake.Sequence.end
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)","Protocol.handleNetworkError
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:364:14)","Connection._handleNetworkError
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:421:18)","Connection._handleConnectTimeout
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:417:8)","Socket.g
>   (events.js:260:16)","emitNone (events.js:67:13)","Socket.emit
>   (events.js:166:7)","Socket._onTimeout (net.js:318:8)","_runOnTimeout
>   (timers.js:524:11)","_makeTimerTimeout
>   (timers.js:515:3)","Timer.unrefTimeout (timers.js:584:5)"]}

after 2-3 retries it works

Comment: This doesn't really help answer the question.